# how to append a button to a table

Tags: jquery, html

i have the following code that i populate a table as follows:

```
    $.each(total, function () {
      var div = $('<div></div>');
      var tabel = $('<table style="width:98%"></table>');
      var body = $('<tbody></tbody>');
     $.each($(this).children('div'), function (i) {
     body.append($('<tr><td style="width:100%">' + $(this).html() + '</td></tr>'));
  });
    tabel.append(body);
    div.append(tabel);
    divs.push(div);
    });
```

which gives me the following html structure

```
<table style="width:98%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:100%">Total: <span class="total">R 0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:100%"><span> BLAH BLAH BLAH</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i want to add a button into the table after the total but i cant get the position right.if i do the following it obviously adds the button first.how do i get it to add after the "total" tr?

```
    body.prepend($('<tr><td>' + '<button type="button" class="Now disabled">Now</button>' + ' <td></tr>'));
   $.each($(this).children('div'), function (i) {
    body.append($('<tr><td style="width:100%">' + $(this).html() + '</td></tr>'));
                                });
```

this is my objective

```
<table style="width:98%">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:100%">Total: <span class="total">R 0.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button type="button" class="Now disabled">Now</button></td> //i want it to come in here
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:100%"><span> BLAH BLAH BLAH</span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not add an if statement in your inner $.each which checks if "i" equals 0 and if so, append your button after you've appended your 1st row.

```
    $.each(total, function () {
      var div = $('<div></div>');
      var tabel = $('<table style="width:98%"></table>');
      var body = $('<tbody></tbody>');
     $.each($(this).children('div'), function (i) {
         body.append($('<tr><td style="width:100%">' + $(this).html() + '</td></tr>'));
         if (i === 0) {
            body.append($('<tr><td style="width:100%"><button>BUTTON STUFF HERE</button></td></tr>'));
         }
  });
    tabel.append(body);
    div.append(tabel);
    divs.push(div);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first select the element of span with class `total` and after that select its `tr` parent and after it, you insert your button code.
Just change your code with below lines -

```
$.each($(this).children('div'), function (i) {
    body.append($('<tr><td style="width:100%">' + $(this).html() + '</td></tr>'));
});
body.find('span.total').closest('tr').after('<tr><td><button type="button" class="Now disabled">Now</button><td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.each(total, function () {
          var div = $('<div></div>');
          var tabel = $('<table style="width:98%"></table>');
          var body = $('<tbody></tbody>');
         $.each($(this).children('div'), function (i) {
         body.append($('<tr><td style="width:100%">' + $(this).html() + '</td> 
         </tr><tr><td><button type="button" class="Now disabled">Now</button> 
   </td></tr>'));
      });
        tabel.append(body);
        div.append(tabel);
        divs.push(div);
        });
```